# How to update UI on the same page according to DropDownItem selected from Custom DropDown?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a custom dropdown on a page which have a dropdown button, an overlay entry containing dropdown items. Now I want to change the other part of page excluding drop down button to change according to dropdown item clicked. e.g. If I click on Dashboard Item then overlay entry should be closed and Dashboard() widget should be displayed below dropdown button, if I click Orders, Orders() widget should be displayed.

Following is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:suture_house/User/UI/Screens/AccountOptions/account_details.dart';
import 'package:suture_house/User/UI/Screens/AccountOptions/addresses.dart';
import 'package:suture_house/User/UI/Screens/AccountOptions/dashboard.dart';
import 'package:suture_house/User/UI/Screens/AccountOptions/downloads.dart';

import 'AccountOptions/orders.dart';

class AccountPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;

  const AccountPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AccountPageState createState() => _AccountPageState();
}

class _AccountPageState extends State<AccountPage> {
  GlobalKey? _actionKey;
  double height = 0.0, width = 0.0, xPosition = 0.0, yPosition = 0.0;
  bool isDropdownOpened = false;
  OverlayEntry? floatingDropDown;
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  //List of pages to display as one of the children of ListView according to selected dropdown item
  final options = [
    Dashboard(),
    Orders(),
    Downloads(),
    Addresses(),
    AccountDetails()
  ];

  // void _onItemTapped(int index) {
  //   setState(() {
  //     _selectedIndex = index;
  //   });
  // }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _actionKey = LabeledGlobalKey(widget.text);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    floatingDropDown!.remove();
    super.dispose();
  }

  //To get the position of Custom DropDown Button
  void findDropDownData() {
    RenderBox renderBox =
        _actionKey!.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    height = renderBox.size.height;
    width = renderBox.size.width;
    Offset offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    xPosition = offset.dx;
    yPosition = offset.dy;
  }

  //Overlay Entry of DropDown Items
  OverlayEntry _createFloatingDropDown() {
    return OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      return Positioned(
        left: xPosition,
        width: width,
        top: yPosition + height,
        height: 6 * height + 60,

        child: DropDown(
          itemHeight: height,
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        //Custom Drop down button
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: GestureDetector(
            key: _actionKey,
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                if (isDropdownOpened) {
                  floatingDropDown!.remove();
                } else {
                  findDropDownData();
                  floatingDropDown = _createFloatingDropDown();
                  Overlay.of(context)!.insert(floatingDropDown!);
                }

                isDropdownOpened = !isDropdownOpened;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8), color: Colors.indigo),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    widget.text,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        //Here I want to display different widgets according to DropDown Item clicked
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            if (isDropdownOpened) {
              floatingDropDown!.remove();
              isDropdownOpened = false;
            }
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 1000,

          )
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}


//This DropDown will be displayed on Overlay Entry
class DropDown extends StatelessWidget {
  final double itemHeight;
  //final void Function(int) onOptionTap;

  const DropDown({Key? key, required this.itemHeight,}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment(-0.85, 0),
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: ArrowClipper(),
            child: Container(
              height: 20,
              width: 30,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.indigo,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Material(
          elevation: 20,
          shape: ArrowShape(),
          child: Container(
            height: 6 * itemHeight,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                DropDownItem.first(
                    text: 'Dashboard',
                    iconData: Icons.speed_outlined,
                    index: 0,
                    isSelected: true),
                DropDownItem(
                    text: 'Orders',
                    iconData: Icons.shopping_bag_outlined,
                    index: 1,
                    isSelected: false),
                DropDownItem(
                    text: 'Downloads',
                    iconData: Icons.insert_drive_file_outlined,
                    index: 2,
                    isSelected: false),
                DropDownItem(
                    text: 'Addresses',
                    iconData: Icons.edit_location,
                    index: 3,
                    isSelected: false),
                DropDownItem(
                    text: 'Account Details',
                    iconData: Icons.person_outline,
                    index: 4,
                    isSelected: false),
                DropDownItem.last(
                    text: 'Logout',
                    iconData: Icons.exit_to_app_outlined,
                    index: 5,
                    isSelected: false),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

}

//DropDown Items
class DropDownItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final IconData iconData;
  bool isSelected;
  final bool isFirstItem;
  final bool isLastItem;
  final int index;

  DropDownItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.iconData,
    required this.isSelected,
    this.isFirstItem = false,
    this.isLastItem = false,
    required this.index,
  }) : super(key: key);

  factory DropDownItem.first(
      {required String text,
      required IconData iconData,
      required bool isSelected,
      required int index}) {
    return DropDownItem(
      text: text,
      iconData: iconData,
      isFirstItem: true,
      isSelected: isSelected,
      index: index,
    );
  }

  factory DropDownItem.last(
      {required String text,
      required IconData iconData,
      required bool isSelected,
      required int index}) {
    return DropDownItem(
      text: text,
      iconData: iconData,
      isLastItem: true,
      isSelected: isSelected,
      index: index,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                top: isFirstItem ? Radius.circular(8) : Radius.zero,
                bottom: isLastItem ? Radius.circular(8) : Radius.zero),
            color: isSelected ? Colors.orangeAccent : Colors.indigo),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Icon(
              iconData,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ArrowClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();

    path.moveTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}

class ArrowShape extends ShapeBorder {
  @override
  // TODO: implement dimensions
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    // TODO: implement getInnerPath
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    // TODO: implement getOuterPath
    return getClip(rect.size);
    //throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    // TODO: implement paint
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) {
    // TODO: implement scale
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();

    path.moveTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);

    return path;
  }
}
```

This is the UI of application. I want to change the UI below "View Options" according to item selected.

[image]

Comment: If not with this, how can I implement same thing I want using flutter's default Dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have made some changes to your code. I am posting the changed code. You can find the changes that I made by searching for ///CHANGES :::

The changes that I have made are simply creating a method to call setState in your widget and passing that method to the DropDownItem.

```
import 'package:suture_house/User/UI/Screens/AccountOptions/account_details.dart';
import 'package:suture_house/User/UI/Screens/AccountOptions/addresses.dart';
import 'package:suture_house/User/UI/Screens/AccountOptions/dashboard.dart';
import 'package:suture_house/User/UI/Screens/AccountOptions/downloads.dart';

import 'AccountOptions/orders.dart';

class AccountPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;

  const AccountPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AccountPageState createState() => _AccountPageState();
}

class _AccountPageState extends State<AccountPage> {
  GlobalKey? _actionKey;
  double height = 0.0, width = 0.0, xPosition = 0.0, yPosition = 0.0;
  bool isDropdownOpened = false;
  OverlayEntry? floatingDropDown;
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  //List of pages to display as one of the children of ListView according to selected dropdown item
  final options = [Dashboard(), Orders(), Downloads(), Addresses(), AccountDetails()];

  // void _onItemTapped(int index) {
  //   setState(() {
  //     _selectedIndex = index;
  //   });
  // }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _actionKey = LabeledGlobalKey(widget.text);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    floatingDropDown!.remove();
    super.dispose();
  }

  //To get the position of Custom DropDown Button
  void findDropDownData() {
    RenderBox renderBox = _actionKey!.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    height = renderBox.size.height;
    width = renderBox.size.width;
    Offset offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    xPosition = offset.dx;
    yPosition = offset.dy;
  }

  //Overlay Entry of DropDown Items
  OverlayEntry _createFloatingDropDown() {
    return OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      return Positioned(
        left: xPosition,
        width: width,
        top: yPosition + height,
        height: 6 * height + 60,
        child: DropDown(
          itemHeight: height,

          ///CHANGES ::: Passing the method to rebuild the widget to DropDown
          onOptionTap: _onDropDownItemTap,
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  ///CHANGES ::: Method to execute when dropdown item is tapped
  _onDropDownItemTap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        //Custom Drop down button
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: GestureDetector(
            key: _actionKey,
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                if (isDropdownOpened) {
                  floatingDropDown!.remove();
                } else {
                  findDropDownData();
                  floatingDropDown = _createFloatingDropDown();
                  Overlay.of(context)!.insert(floatingDropDown!);
                }

                isDropdownOpened = !isDropdownOpened;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8), color: Colors.indigo),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    widget.text,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        //Here I want to display different widgets according to DropDown Item clicked
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            if (isDropdownOpened) {
              floatingDropDown!.remove();
              isDropdownOpened = false;
            }
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 1000,
            ///CHANGES ::: Showing the widget with the selected index here
            child: options[_selectedIndex],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

//This DropDown will be displayed on Overlay Entry
class DropDown extends StatelessWidget {
  final double itemHeight;
  final void Function(int)? onOptionTap;

  DropDown({Key? key, required this.itemHeight, this.onOptionTap}) : super(key: key);

  final List<DropDownModel> dropDownModelList = [
    DropDownModel(text: 'Dashboard', iconData: Icons.speed_outlined, index: 0, isSelected: true),
    DropDownModel(text: 'Orders', iconData: Icons.shopping_bag_outlined, index: 1, isSelected: false),
    DropDownModel(text: 'Downloads', iconData: Icons.insert_drive_file_outlined, index: 2, isSelected: false),
    DropDownModel(text: 'Addresses', iconData: Icons.edit_location, index: 3, isSelected: false),
    DropDownModel(text: 'Account Details', iconData: Icons.person_outline, index: 4, isSelected: false),
    DropDownModel(text: 'Logout', iconData: Icons.exit_to_app_outlined, index: 5, isSelected: false),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment(-0.85, 0),
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: ArrowClipper(),
            child: Container(
              height: 20,
              width: 30,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.indigo,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Material(
          elevation: 20,
          shape: ArrowShape(),
          child: Container(
            height: 6 * itemHeight,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ///CHANGES ::: Passing the optionTap method to DropDownItems
                ...List.generate(
                  dropDownModelList.length,
                  (index) {
                    var model = dropDownModelList[index];
                    return DropDownItem(
                      text: model.text,
                      iconData: model.iconData,
                      isSelected: index == 0, //I set it as first item based on your code. You can change the condition if necessary.
                      isFirstItem: index == 0,
                      isLastItem: index == dropDownModelList.length - 1,
                      index: index,
                      onOptionTap: onOptionTap,
                    );
                  },
                ),
                
                ///CHANGES ::: Commented out your code
                // DropDownItem.first(text: 'Dashboard', iconData: Icons.speed_outlined, index: 0, isSelected: true, onOptionTap: onOptionTap),
                // DropDownItem(text: 'Orders', iconData: Icons.shopping_bag_outlined, index: 1, isSelected: false),
                // DropDownItem(text: 'Downloads', iconData: Icons.insert_drive_file_outlined, index: 2, isSelected: false),
                // DropDownItem(text: 'Addresses', iconData: Icons.edit_location, index: 3, isSelected: false),
                // DropDownItem(text: 'Account Details', iconData: Icons.person_outline, index: 4, isSelected: false),
                // DropDownItem.last(text: 'Logout', iconData: Icons.exit_to_app_outlined, index: 5, isSelected: false),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class DropDownModel {
  String text;
  IconData iconData;
  int index;
  bool isSelected;

  DropDownModel({
    required this.text,
    required this.iconData,
    required this.index,
    required this.isSelected,
  });
}

//DropDown Items
class DropDownItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final IconData iconData;
  bool isSelected;
  final bool isFirstItem;
  final bool isLastItem;
  final int index;

  ///CHANGES ::: passing the onTap
  final void Function(int)? onOptionTap;

  DropDownItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.iconData,
    required this.isSelected,
    this.isFirstItem = false,
    this.isLastItem = false,
    required this.index,
    this.onOptionTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  /*factory DropDownItem.first({
    required String text,
    required IconData iconData,
    required bool isSelected,
    required int index,
    this.onOptionTap,
  }) {
    return DropDownItem(
      text: text,
      iconData: iconData,
      isFirstItem: true,
      isSelected: isSelected,
      index: index,
      onOptionTap: onOptionTap,
    );
  }

  factory DropDownItem.last({required String text, required IconData iconData, required bool isSelected, required int index}) {
    return DropDownItem(
      text: text,
      iconData: iconData,
      isLastItem: true,
      isSelected: isSelected,
      index: index,
    );
  }*/

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      ///CHANGES ::: Executing the onTap method
      onTap: () {
        if (onOptionTap != null) {
          onOptionTap!(index);
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: isFirstItem ? Radius.circular(8) : Radius.zero, bottom: isLastItem ? Radius.circular(8) : Radius.zero),
            color: isSelected ? Colors.orangeAccent : Colors.indigo),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Icon(
              iconData,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ArrowClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();

    path.moveTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}

class ArrowShape extends ShapeBorder {
  @override
  // TODO: implement dimensions
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    // TODO: implement getInnerPath
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    // TODO: implement getOuterPath
    return getClip(rect.size);
    //throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    // TODO: implement paint
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) {
    // TODO: implement scale
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();

    path.moveTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);

    return path;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It worked and also you explained it very well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

use option[_selectedIndex] wherever you want to show the widget.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this do not complete the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditions to update your UI based on the option chosen, so when you make the change you're doing using options[_selectedIndex] then you have the option that you want to display and then you can do something like this

```
options[_selectedIndex]==dashboard? dashboardWidget(): 
options[_selectedIndex]==settings? settingsWidget():defaultWidget(),
```

and I recommend You using Enums that'll help reduce your code and make it more flexible for upcoming changes or maintainance of the code

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this do not complete the solution.